# Three identical views = Different numbers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

For my website, which I'm tracking with Google Tag Manager and Universal Analytics, I have three identical views (i.e. I simply copied the original view). For the same time-frame (in this case February 10th), they all show slightly different visitor numbers. How is that possible? They are not using any filters, and even if they were, they would still be identical copies (no?).

Thank you!

Original View:
[image: Original View]

Copy 1 of Original View:
[image: Copy 1 of Original View]

Copy 2 of Original View:
[image: Copy 2 of Original View]

Comment: It can take up to 48hrs for data to process properly so I'd give it another 24hrs and then recheck